# Which JsonWebToken library can I use in Postman

Tags: jwt, postman

I have the following pre-request script in Postman which I am trying to use to get an RS512 signed token. I tried using crypto-js but from what I read, it is symetric key only so it does not support the RS512 algorithm

```
pm.sendRequest("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsrsasign/8.0.20/jsrsasign-all-min.js", (error, response) => {
  if (error || response.code !== 200) {
      pm.expect.fail('Could not load external library');
  }

  var text = response.text();

  eval(text);

  var pvtKey = pm.environment.get('private-secret-key') || ''

  var jwtSecret = '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n'
  jwtSecret += pvtKey + '\n'
  jwtSecret += '-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----';

  var currentTimestamp = Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);

  var jwtPostPayload = {
      'iat': currentTimestamp,
      "name": "John Doe"
  };

  var token = sign(jwtPostPayload, jwtSecret, { algorithm: 'RS512' })
  pm.environment.set('jwt-signed', token);
});
```

My problem now is that none of the libraries that I import seem to work. I've tried all of these https://jwt.io/libraries?language=JavaScript and I either get `module is not defined` or `window is not defined` or `navigator is not defined`. I wouldn't mind copying the minified js and just making some small changes and storing it as a global variable, I just don't know which changes to make.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a library that will work like this or otherwise just tell me the changes I need to make to get the window or module error resolved?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but I've been using this library from the list https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign/blob/master/jsrsasign-all-min.js

First I got those errors about the window and navigator but they were fixed just declaring some in my prescript, something like this:

```
const navigator = {}; //fake a navigator object for the lib
const window = {}; //fake a window object for the lib
eval(pm.globals.get('jsrsasign-js')); //import javascript jsrsasign
const signedRO = KJUR.jws.JWS.sign("RS256", header, payload, jwk);
```

This worked for me to generate a RS256 jwt.

Regards

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).